# Route [tasks.complete] not defined. (View: /Users/pathparakh/Projects/task/resources/views/tasks/index.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

This is my TaskController where complete() function is defined to store done_at current time

```
public function complete($id)
{
    $task = Task::create([
        'done_at' => now(),
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('tasks.index')->withSuccess('Done');
}
```

This is my web.php route

```
Route::post('/tasks/complete', 'TaskController@complete');
```

This is my index page where there is submit button to save current time

```
<form action="{{ route('tasks.complete', $task->id) }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: you need to define named route for tasks complete action which you havent defined

Answer (score 4):

You missed name declaration of your route, like this:

```
Route::post('/tasks/complete', 'TaskController@complete')->name('tasks.complete');
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: If you want to add new task use the first one, but if you want to update an existing task use the second one:

//---First:

TaskController:

```
public function complete() {
    $task = Task::create([
        'done_at' => now(),
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('tasks.index')->withSuccess('Done');
}
```

web.php

```
Route::post('/tasks/complete', 'TaskController@complete')->name('tasks.complete');
```

Your view file(index page):

```
<form action="{{ route('tasks.complete') }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

//---Second:

Or if you need to pass the id parameter in your controller you should use the below code:

TaskController:

```
public function complete($id) {
    $task = Task::findOrFail($id);
    if ($task) {
        $task->update([
            'done_at' => now()
        ]);
        return redirect()->route('tasks.index')->withSuccess('Done');
    }
    return redirect()->route('tasks.index')->withSuccess('Task No Found');
}
```

web.php

```
Route::post('/tasks/complete/{id}', 'TaskController@complete')->name('tasks.complete');
```

Your view file(index page):

```
<form action="{{ route('tasks.complete', ['id' => $task->id]) }}" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

As per your complete() function in the controller and as per the form action,

Your route should look like this:

```
Route::post('/tasks/complete/{id}', 'taskcontroller@complete')->name('tasks.complete');
```